# R/Shiny: how to use observe() to toggle data input

Tags: r, select, shiny

This question confused me a lot. I would like to make `data3` link to `data3c` when `input$SelectedYear` is 2017 and `input$SelectedMon` is "Apr" and otherwise `data3` is linked to `data31`.

I would like to use `observe()` function to fulfill it but the code is not working.

ui.r:

```
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Data"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
selectInput("SelectedYear", "Choose a Year:", 
             choices = 
               c(2009, 2010,2015,2016,2016,2017)),

uiOutput("selectionMon"),

uiOutput("selectionFY"),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
tableOutput("distPlot")
)
)
)
```

server.r:

```
library(shiny)

## data31 (Historical data)
PeriodYear<-c(2009, 2010,2015,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017)
PeriodMon<-c("Jan","Apr","Jul","Sep","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Apr")

YARD_ID<-c(33,25,47,13,64,24,26,36,34,89)

Value<-c(1,3,6,2,4,6,7,2,3,1)

dataall<-data.frame(PeriodYear,PeriodMon,YARD_ID,Value)

dataall$PeriodMon<-as.character(dataall$PeriodMon)

data31<-dataall[which(dataall$PeriodYear!=2017 | dataall$PeriodMon!="Apr"),]

## data3c (current month)

data3c<-dataall[which(dataall$PeriodYear==2017 & dataall$PeriodMon=="Apr"),]

data3<-data31

current_year<-2017
current_mon<-"Apr"

# data3<-data31
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

observe({ 
data3<-data31
if (!is.null(data3)) {
  if (length(data3) > 0) {
    if (!is.null(input$SelectedYear) & !is.null(input$SelectedMon) ) {
      if ( (input$SelectedYear > 0) & (input$SelectedMon > 0 ) ){ 
        Year_input <- isolate(input$SelectedYear)
        Mon_input <- isolate(input$SelectedMon)
        Id.Year <- which(current_year == Year_input)
        Id.Mon <- which(current_mon == Mon_input)
        if (length(Id.Year) > 0 & length( Id.Mon) > 0 ) {
          data3<-data3c
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
 })


output$distPlot <- renderTable({

head(dataselect()) 

})


######## UI input of month #####
output$selectionMon<-renderUI({
Mondata1<-data3[which(data3$PeriodYear==input$SelectedYear),]
selectInput("SelectedMon", "Choose a Month:", 
            choices = names(table(data.frame(Mondata1$PeriodMon))))
})
##### End of input of month ####

######## UI input of FeedYard #####
output$selectionFY<-renderUI({
FYdata<-data3[which(data3$PeriodYear==input$SelectedYear & 
                      data3$PeriodMon==input$SelectedMon),]
selectInput("SelectedFY", "Choose a ID:", 
            choices =names(table(data.frame(FYdata$YARD_ID))))

})

dataselect<-reactive({
data3[which(data3$PeriodYear==input$SelectedYear & 
              data3$PeriodMon==input$SelectedMon &       data3$YARD_ID==input$SelectedFY),]
 })
  ##### 

 })
```

Everything else works fine only the `data3` didn't switch (still `data31`) to `data3c` when selection is Apr 2017.

I appreciate any replies!

Thank you!

Comment: you should use a `reactive()` function or `reactiveValues()` for that. You attempt a "global" assignment of data3, but that wont work,...

Comment: Hi, @BigDataScientist. Thank you so much for your help. I tried `reactive()` but I got an error `Error in if: argument is of length zero`, maybe because I set a `uiOutput()` for the third menu. I am not sure what's wrong with it. Thank you again!

Comment: well stackoverflow is not for debugging code, the only hint i could give is that  `reactiveValues()`might be easier to learn,....good luck!

Comment: Sure. I will figure it out soon. Thank you again!

Comment: @Joanna I'm willing to help, but at the outset I'm a bit disconcerted.  Where is `data3`, or `data31` defined in the first place? Maybe something got missed in pasting?

Comment: Hi, @Enzo. Thank you so much! The `data31` is a dataframe with records from year 2000 to Mar, 2017 and the `data3c`is a data frame with the same structure of current month (Apr, 2017). I would like to make `data3` as a flexible input when users select "April 2017" `data3=data3c` and otherwise `data3=data31`. The idea behind it is I am building a real time shiny app linked with MySQL database. However, data is too large so take too long to load it. So, I save historical data (Year 2000 to last month) into RDS only when user select current month, I loaded the data of current month from mySQL.

Comment: great, but my point is that the code above has NO definition of data3, or data31 or data3c.  Care to add say two rows + header to the code, please?

Comment: @Enzo. Thank you! I made up the datasets so now the code is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below, that sort of work.

Unfortunately, as I was in full "debug mode", while I was experimenting I made more changes to your code than what was justified.

For example, I wasted a good bit of time on one typical issue that happened to me in the past.

When you have a selector it is always good practice to "derive" them from live data.  For example a year selector could have been derived from your `data31` selecting`unique(data31$PeriodYear)` or something similar.

In reality I wasted time as there were years not present in the data and this was obviously not liked by the app. My bad!

Another similar suggestion in a similar vein, is to check if the selected year (in this example) is actually **in** the data before doing the subsetting  (especially when you have loads of filters is easy to loose track of what is happening).

One more issue: `observeEvent` to my knowledge is designed to work primarily with one reactive condition (I am not sure of this and I'll probably post a question on shiny mailing list, to see if I get any confirmation).  To avoid an half-backed solution I decided to revert to the *old* observe, where you can have any number of reactive triggers. I will let you know if I find something different.

```
library(shiny)

rm(list=ls()) 

## data31 (Historical data)
PeriodYear<-c(2009, 2010,2015,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017)
PeriodMon<-c("Jan","Apr","Jul","Sep","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Apr")
YARD_ID<-c(33,25,47,13,64,24,26,36,34,89)
Value<-c(1,3,6,2,4,6,7,2,3,1)
dataall <- data.frame(PeriodYear,PeriodMon,YARD_ID,Value, 
                stringsAsFactors = F)
# dataall$PeriodMon<-as.character(dataall$PeriodMon)
data31<-dataall[which(dataall$PeriodYear!=2017 | dataall$PeriodMon!="Apr"),]

## data3c (current month)
data3c<-dataall[which(dataall$PeriodYear==2017 & dataall$PeriodMon=="Apr"),]
data3<-data31
current_year<-2017
current_mon<-"Apr"

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Data"),
  column(4,
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  selectInput("SelectedYear", "Choose a Year:", 
                 choices = 
                   c(2009,2010,2015,2016,2017))

  ,uiOutput("selectionMon"),

  uiOutput("selectionFY")
  ),
  column(8,
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("distPlot")
  )
) )


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({ 

    if (length(input$SelectedYear) == 0 | is.null(input$SelectedMon)  ) return()
    if(input$SelectedMon == "" ) return()

    data3 <<- data3 <- data31
    if (is.null(data3) | length(data3) == 0) return()
    isolate({

            Year_input <- input$SelectedYear
            Mon_input <- input$SelectedMon
            Id.Year <- which(current_year == Year_input)
            Id.Mon <- which(current_mon == Mon_input)
            if (length(Id.Year) > 0 & length( Id.Mon) > 0 ) data3<<-data3c

            }) # end isolate    
  })


  output$distPlot <- renderTable({

    head(dataselect()) 

  })

  ######## UI input of month #####
  output$selectionMon<-renderUI({

  if (length(input$SelectedYear) == 0 ) return()
    Mondata1<-data3[which(data3$PeriodYear==input$SelectedYear),]
    selectInput("SelectedMon", "Choose a Month:", 
                choices = names(table(data.frame(Mondata1$PeriodMon))))
  })
  ##### End of input of month ####

  ######## UI input of FeedYard #####
  output$selectionFY<-renderUI({
    if(length(input$SelectedYear) ==0 | length(input$SelectedMon) == 0 ) return()

    FYdata<-data3[which(data3$PeriodYear==input$SelectedYear & 
                          data3$PeriodMon==input$SelectedMon),]
    selectInput("SelectedFY", "Choose a ID:", 
                choices =names(table(data.frame(FYdata$YARD_ID))))

  })

  dataselect<-reactive({ 
    if(length(input$SelectedYear) ==0 | length(input$SelectedMon) == 0 | 
       length(input$SelectedFY) ==  0) return()
    isolate({
    data3[which(data3$PeriodYear==input$SelectedYear & 
                  data3$PeriodMon==input$SelectedMon & data3$YARD_ID==input$SelectedFY),]
  }) #end isolate

  })
  ##### 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so so much! The only one modification is to change `selectInput("SelectedMon", "Choose a Month:", 
                choices = names(table(data.frame(Mondata1$PeriodMon))) )` into `selectInput("SelectedMon", "Choose a Month:", 
                choices = c(names(table(data.frame(Mondata1$PeriodMon))), "Apr") )` because it is "SelectedMon" is an `uiOutput` (subset of "SelectedYear") and the initial data didn't include "2017 Apr".  Another solution is to update 'Mon' as factor by `dataall$PeriodMon<-factor(dataall$PeriodMon,month.abb)` so the month selection is fixed.

Comment: Maybe it is my personal taste and sense of aesthetics, but I would try to simplify your `c(names(table(data.frame(Mondata1$PeriodMon))), "Apr")`!

Comment: Thanks, @Enzo. I appreciate you. I agree that a selector should be derived from live data. So, I changed "SelectedYear" into `selectizeInput("SelectedYear", "Choose a Year:", 
                        choices = names(table(data.frame(data3$PeriodYear))),options = list(
                          placeholder = 'Please select an option below',
                          onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                        )),`. In this way, selector of Year will derive from live data.